# Thermic isolation for 3D printer buildplate

Tags: heat-conduction

I have questions about heat conduction, directly related to a problem I have with my 3D printer.

Here is (schematic) front view of my 3D printer buildplate:

[image]

The orange top plate is a PCB heated bed (a piece of metal aluminium heated from the inside). The cyan bottom plate is the mount plate for the heat bed. The mount plate is screwed on plastic parts (the blue circles). The plastic parts contain bearings, so the entire system can slide. The small green rectangles are screws to attach the heat bed to the mount plate. Note that the screws are not directly in contact with the mount plate. There is a plastic adaptor on the mount plate for each screw, so that the heat from the heat bed can't be conducted to the mount plate through the screws.

At the moment, there is an air gap of 7 mm between the heat bed and the mount plate. The wattage for the heat bed is supposed to be 115~144 Watts for my setting. When printing, the system moves on one axis, so there is a little ventilation from the movement.

When I set my heat bed to 80°C, "a lot" of heat goes through the mount plate. The plastic parts under the mount plate are made of PLA and start deforming, which is a problem (PLA starts deforming around 60°C). At the moment, I'm using fans under the mount plate to evacuate the heat.

What I don't understand is why so much heat goes through the mount plate, and what I could do about it. From my basic understanding of physics, air is supposed to be a better thermal insulation than any solid, so putting something (like a piece of cork) between the two plates won't help. Which brings me to a second (unrelated) question.

The image below could totally be the interior and exterior walls of a house. If air is a better insulation than any solid, why do we put insulation in our walls?